# Determining whether software change had any impact on execution time

Tags: statistics, benchmarking, difference, t-test

It's been some while since I took my statistics course, so I need some help figuring out how to compare two results.

I have a software that I can run with multiple cores. To get some confidence in the performance, I run it many times for each core configuration and collect the execution times.

I now implement a change in this software, and collect results exactly the same way that I previously did it. I now have two lists of execution times of length `N * M`, where `N` is the number of cores I have, and `M` is the number of times that I run the software.

How can I statistically determine whether the change made any difference? I have dusted off my statistics book and believe that the ***paired t-test*** is appropriate. What makes me unsure is that I change the number of cores a couple of times, even though the change happens at the same point in the modified software as well. As an example, execution time might drop form 10 seconds to six seconds when I go from one to two cores, but the relative difference between the pairwise measurements don't really change.

Does it make any sense to perform `N` paired t-tests, where each test is done on the measurements from running the software on a specific number of cores?